# Proving periodic points of tent-map are dense in [0,1]

Tags: dynamical-systems, periodic-functions

Let $T$ be the tent map defined by $$T = \begin{cases} 2x \quad \text{ if } x \le 1/2 \\ 2(1-x) \quad \text{ if } x \ge 1/2\end{cases}$$
I am trying to prove that the periodic points of $T$ are dense in the unit interval, $I = [0,1]$. I know that all asymptotically periodic orbits of $T$ are eventually periodic, given that all fixed points are sources. However, I'm struggling in going about solving this given the tools I have. For context, this problem is problem 3.7 in Alligood's text. I was thinking that showing there are infinitely many periodic orbits is sufficient, but I'm unsure. I'm trying to find a more rigorous proof but am at a loss.

Comment: I think the simplest way to prove that periodic points of tent map are dense in $\lbrack 0, 1 \rbrack$ is to use binary expansion of $x$. If you write $x$ as $0, a_1 a_2 a_3 \dots $ then $T(x) = 0, a_2 a_3 \dots$. Note that if you take $ x = 0, a_1 a_2 a_3 \dots a_m \dots $ and $\overline{x}_m = 0, (a_1 a_2 a_ 3 \dots a_m)$ then $\vert x - \overline{x}_m \vert < 2^{-m}$. Also note that $\overline{x}_m$ is a periodic point of period $m$ or less. We can say now that if we vary $m$ we can find a periodic point arbitrarily close to any point $x$. Thus periodic points are dense.

Comment: @Evgeny You are describing the doubling map, not the tent map. But it hapens that a "tweaked" binary representation of real numbers in [0,1] does the job, see the question linked as a duplicate.

Comment: And this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/948090/

Comment: And this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1092863/

Comment: And this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1885312

Comment: @Did My bad, writing comments at night is sometimes a bad idea :)